# How do I remove this exterior Water Valve cap?

Tags: plumbing, exterior

How do I remove this exterior water valve cap? 
[image: cap]

Bonus points for a name!

Update:
I cleaned it a bit more:
[image: cleaned cap]

I attempted to pry it but, I haven't made much progress:
[image: pry cap]

I also noticed this bolt but I don't think I have a wrench for it.
[image: bolt]

Comment: They look like they could use a special tool, but have you tried digging out the ground around them and just unscrewing them?

Comment: Its pretty flimsy. It feels like it might just pop off but it keeps breaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful what you are prying up on, the 5 sided nut is what removes the cast iron top. usually the city only wants a licensed plumber to open these, if not the city plumber only. I refer to it as city since it is not a well. Those plastic items on top may very well be the remote sensor to read the usage for billing. It is just a guess, I have never seen anything like that above/on the cast iron cover. Usually the cover is removed to read the gallons used. but this seems a hi-tech model....

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to quit messing with it. Thanks for the verification.

Comment: Jack is right, don't mess with it. Even though it is on your property, it is owned by the water company and they will hold you responsible if you damage it. The piece you are prying on actually screws on and off with a special wrench.